# Docker Compose MongoDB Config /etc/mongodb.conf: Is a Directory

Tags: mongodb, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, digital-ocean

I am trying to run a MongoDB container on a DigitalOcean droplet and so created a new dir with `mkdir -pv mongodb/data` then inside mongodb I created a new file with `touch mongodb.conf` then edited it with `nano mongodb.conf` so that it looks like this:

```
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
   logAppend: true
storage:
   journal:
      enabled: true
processManagement:
   fork: true
net:
   bindIp: 0.0.0.0
   port: 27017
setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
```

I then used the same process to create a file `docker-compose.yml` Which looks like:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    volumes:
      - /mongodb/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
      - /mongodb/data:/data/db
    command: ["mongod", "--config", "/etc/mongod.conf"]
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:27017:27017
```

This makes the filesystem look like:

```
.
├── mongodb
│   ├── data
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   └── mongod.conf
```

When I then try running `docker-compose up` it gives the error:

```
mongodb    | grep: /etc/mongo/mongod.conf: Is a directory
mongodb    | error: unexpected "js-yaml.js" output while parsing config:
mongodb    | undefined
mongodb exited with code 1
```

I have also tried changing the command to: `command: ["mongod", "-f", "/etc/mongod.conf"]` but this gives a similar error:

```
mongodb    | Error opening config file: Is a directory
mongodb    | try 'mongod --help' for more information
mongodb exited with code 2
```

Any help to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the path to your `mongod.conf` on the host *really* `/mongodb/mongod.conf`? Or is it `./mongodb/mongod.conf`? The difference is significant (the same goes for your `data` directory).

Comment: @larsks Thank you for your reply. I tried changing my docker-compose.yml file volumes to:
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
      - ./mongodb/data:/data/db
As you suggested. This however is still giving the same error.

Comment: When you specify paths in your `docker-compose.yml` file, they need to be *relative to `docker-compose.yml`*, or they need to be absolute paths (start with `/`). Given what you show in your question, it looks like the relative path from `docker-compose.yml` to `mongod.conf` is simply `./mongod.conf`.

Comment: @larsks Thank you for your help. I managed to get it working as expected by removing the container and image then running the docker-compose again. I assume it was a problem with the filesystem on the container then? Not too sure but at least it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I did it following way:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    volumes:
      - /mongodb/cnf:/etc/mongo/
      - /mongodb/data:/data/db
    command: ["mongod", "--config", "/etc/mongo/mongod.conf"]
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:27017:27017
```

Then just put your mongod.conf in /mongodb/cnf on host machine